# How to setup the TypeScript compiler for the library so that the unused modules will be cut off by Webpack in the dependents projects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

### Preliminary explanations about subject library

I am sorry about taking your time by making you read this. I wrote it to answer the questions like "What are you doing?" and "Why are you doing this?".

The [library](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-es_extensions) consists from a large number of helper functions an classes. In this regard it's similar to lodash ([check the structure of lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash)), but unlike lodash the source code has been organized by [multilevel directories](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-es_extensions/tree/master/Source). It's comfortable for the developers but could be not comfortable for the users: to import the desired function to project, the user must need to know where it is, e. g.:

```js
import { 
  computeFirstItemNumberForSpecificPaginationPage
} from "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions/Number/Pagination";
```

To solve this problem most of functions has been imported to [`index.ts`](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-es_extensions/blob/master/Source/index.ts) and exported again from there. Now user can get desired function as:

```js
import { 
  computeFirstItemNumberForSpecificPaginationPage 
} from "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions";
```

Please note that all functions in `index.ts` (will be compiled by TypeScript to `index.js`) are intended for both BrowserJS and NodeJS. The functionality especially for BrowserJS is in [`BrowserJS.ts`](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-es_extensions/tree/master/Source) and especially for NodeJS in [`NodeJS.ts`](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-es_extensions/blob/master/Source/NodeJS.ts) (currently is almost empty but the reexporting methodology is same).

Also, until this problem will be solved, I included the compiled JavaScript to the library repository ([`Distributable` directory](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-es_extensions/tree/master/Distributable)).

### Problem

From now, @yamato-daiwa/es-extensions is the **library** and any project which depends on it is the **consuming project**.

I expected that all unused functions/classes of the consuming project will be cut off by [Webpack optimizations](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/). For example, in below case I expected that `isUndefined` function only will be left in Webpack bundle:

```
import { isUndefined } from "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions"

const test: string | undefined = "ALPHA";
console.log(isUndefined(test));
```

But in reallity, Webpack left EVERYTHING from `index.js` of the library. I beautified the minified JavaScript built by Webpack; it is like:

```
(() => {
    "use strict";
    var e = {
            5272: (e, t) => {
                Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", {
                    value: !0
                }), t.default = function(e, t) {
                    for (const [a, n] of e.entries())
                        if (t(n)) return a;
                    return null
                }
            },
            7684: (e, t) => {
                Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", {
                    value: !0
                }), t.default = function(e, t) {
                    const a = [];
                    return e.forEach(((e, n) => {
                        t(e) && a.push(n)
                    })), a
                }
            },
  // ...
```

I suppose everyone understanding that is not acceptable especially for browser applications where each kilobyte on count.

How to solve this problem? The ideal solution (if it exists) will not touch the source files organization, just change the TypeScript configuration.

### Repro

I created [one more repository (repro)](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Issue-WebpackDoesNotCuttOfTheUnusedFunctionality) where you can try above example.

##### Experiment flow

1. Get this repository by VCS
2. Install dependencies as always (`npm i` command).
3. Check the `src/index.ts`. It imports `isUndefined` function from the library and using it.
4. Run `npm run ProductionBuild`
5. Beautify the output `index.js` by tool like [beautifier.io](https://beautifier.io/). You will see that whole library has been bundled while it's desired that only `inUndefined` has been bundled.

### Musings about the cause

The first cause candidate is the using of reexportint pattern, exactly [Source/index.ts](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-es_extensions/blob/master/Source/index.ts), [Source/BrowserJS.ts](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-es_extensions/blob/master/Source/BrowserJS.ts) and [Source/NodeJS](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-es_extensions/blob/master/Source/NodeJS.ts). The compiled `index.js` looks like:

```js
const isStringifiedNonNegativeIntegerOfRegularNotation_1 = require("./Numbers/isStringifiedNonNegativeIntegerOfRegularNotation");
exports.isStringifiedNonNegativeIntegerOfRegularNotation = isStringifiedNonNegativeIntegerOfRegularNotation_1.default;
const separateEach3DigitsGroupWithComma_1 = require("./Numbers/separateEach3DigitsGroupWithComma");
exports.separateEach3DigitsGroupWithComma = separateEach3DigitsGroupWithComma_1.default;
```

([Check full file](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-es_extensions/blob/master/Distributable/index.js))

If to import each function from it's individual module like `import isUndefined from "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions/TypeGuards/isUndefined"` instead of `import { isUndefined } from "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions"`, no redundant code will be output. But as I already told, this solution is unacceptable because the library users must need to know where `isUndefined` and other function has been organized.

The other cause could be the output modules type. Currently it's a `CommonJS`. Here is the
`tsconfig.json` of the library:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",

    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,

    "removeComments": true,

    "outDir": "Distributable/",
    "declaration": true
  },

  "include": [ "Source/**/*" ]
}
```

According to hypothesis, depending on specific modules type the Webpack could bundle the code to monolithic structure where it's impossible to decompose and filter out some modules even if those has not been used.

> Now all these (AMD, UMD, CommonJS) slowly become a part of history,
> but we still can find them in old scripts.
>
> [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/modules-intro)

By the way, the TypeScript configuration in consuming project also could affect (included to repro). Currently it is:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "ES2020",
    "strict": true,

    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@SourceFilesRoot/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If your output from typescript is ES6 then webpack will be able to do tree shaking.  But be aware that if some packages your includes are imported as es5, then they will not be subject to tree shaking.  Not sure if this is the question you were asking, that why I made it a comment.

Comment: @CraigHicks, thank you for the comment. To you mean I need to set the TypeScript compiler building my library to `"target": "ES2015"` or above? Or maybe the the `"module"` must be the `ES**`, not `CommonJS`?

Comment: Yow broh! Why is you trying to reinvent the wheel  there is already a Babel plugin that does that https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-import

Comment: "tree-shaking" is a better term to use than "cut-off".  There is even a "tree-shaking" tag for SO questions.  You could add it to this question.

Comment: I will also take a look at https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-es_extensions/tree/experiment-es2020_modules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you *at least* need to set `module` so that ES6 or above is ouput.  Possible values include

- `"es6"`
- `"es2020"`
- `"esnext"`

The [webpack documentation of tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) says

> Tree shaking is a term commonly used in the JavaScript context for dead-code elimination. It relies on the static structure of ES2015 module syntax, i.e. import and export. The name and concept have been popularized by the ES2015 module bundler rollup.

*Note: `moduleResolution:` can remain as `"node"`

However, a correct `module:` setting is not necessarily sufficient, or may not even be desirable.  See the section below:

- side effects
- imported libraries which are not ES6
- if using babel, babel settings may conflict

##### side effects

> The webpack 2 release came with built-in support for ES2015 modules (alias harmony modules) as well as unused module export detection. The new webpack 4 release expands on this capability with a way to provide hints to the compiler via the "sideEffects" package.json property to denote which files in your project are "pure" and therefore safe to prune if unused.

<s>Actually, it appears that the default value for `sideEffects:` if NOT specified is `false`, so you don't really have to worry about that unless your ES6 code/module has certain side effects so that it SHOULDN'T be tree-shaken.</s>
**In fact setting `sideEffects:false` in the top level `package.json` is critical to enable tree-shaking in your project, as shown below.**

(In a different project depending upon `lodash`, `sideEffects` was not critical.  That may be because of the difference in library directory structure and `index.js`).

##### imported libraries

As an example, regular `loadash` will not be tree shaken because it is it is not es6.
To enable tree shaking in lodash you have to add these packages and explicitly use the es6 version:

```
npm i lodash-es
npm i @types/lodash-es
```

and change you import statements from

```
import * as _ from "lodash"
```

to

```
import * as _ from "lodash-es"
```

See this [SE answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534339/4376643) for a discussion.

##### babel

The [babel doc on its own settings for "module"](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#modules) says

> *modules*
>
> "amd" | "umd" | "systemjs" | "commonjs" | "cjs" | "auto" | false, defaults to "auto".
>
> Enable transformation of ES module syntax to another module type. Note that cjs is just an alias for commonjs.
>
> Setting this to false will preserve ES modules. Use this only if you intend to ship native ES Modules to browsers. If you are using a bundler with Babel, the default modules: "auto" is always preferred.
> modules: "auto"
>
> By default @babel/preset-env uses caller data to determine whether ES modules and module features (e.g. import()) should be transformed. Generally caller data will be specified in the bundler plugins (e.g. babel-loader, @rollup/plugin-babel) and thus it is not recommended to pass caller data yourself -- The passed caller may overwrite the one from bundler plugins and in the future you may get suboptimal results if bundlers supports new module features.

So I guess if you really need babel (and you *might* not need it with webpack4) then you should ensure that "caller" is really specifying "false" so the ES6 stays as "ES6".  In my setup that successfully minified, I was not using "babel".

---

EDIT:  Ran the experimental compile provided on Gihub by the author, but according to the stdout diagnostics, there was not a difference using `"module":"ESNext"` compared to "CommonJS".  Could it be that modules under `@yamato-daiwa/` are not pre compiled to es6?

---

### The Best Solution

### Issue-WebpackDoesNotCuttOfTheUnusedFunctionality

`package.json`

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ProductionBuild": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "sideEffects":false,
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "9.2.3",
    "typescript": "4.3.2",
    "webpack": "5.38.1",
    "webpack-cli": "4.7.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "3.0.0",
    "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions": "file:../yamato_daiwa-es_extensions/Distributable/"
    }
}
```

`"sideEffects":false,` has been added.

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "ES2020",
    "strict": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@SourceFilesRoot/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Module was changed to `"module": "es2020",`

### yamato_daiwa-es_extensions

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",

    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,

    "removeComments": true,

    "outDir": "Distributable/",
    "declaration": true
  },

  "include": [ "Source/**/*" ],
}
```

Module was changed to `"module": "es2020",`

**Use the original `index.ts` file, with no changes**

With the above settings I am getting an output `index.js` of size 39 bytes:

```
(()=>{"use strict";console.log(!1)})();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry, but I cant just replace my settings to yours. Even it will work, this problem will not be solved until we understand what is affecting to tree shaking.  Maybe it's a `"module": "es2020"` setting? I'll check when I get some time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I need some time to do some experiments. For now, I can say that I don't use the babel and currently my library has no dependencies, so most likely the cause is the modules type. It is important to note that there are two `tsconfig.json`s: in library and in consuming project. Which one is more important?

Comment: The `tsconfig.json` settings for the library are required to convert the library to es6+.  And webpack cannot tree shake the library unless it is es6+.  So "both" are important is the correct answer, I believe.  I tried with only the top directory tsconfig.json changed and according to the diag output there was no change in size.

Comment: I create the realize [@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions@0.4.0-experimental](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-es_extensions/tree/experiment-es2020_modules) with `"module": "ES2020"` setting and also added the same setting to [repro](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Issue-WebpackDoesNotCuttOfTheUnusedFunctionality). I am sorry, but output bundle is still polluted by unused functionality. Let me repeat that currently my library has not any dependencies, so the cause is not the dependencies. May I ask you to check the code once more? I'll accept your answer as soon as we find the cause.

Comment: Thank you for the supporting of your answer. I'll check your updated solution, report about results and if it works, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I am very sorry, but the desired effect still not reached yet. I believe your solution is right, just I missed something. First I applied your solution to `isUndefined` and `isNumber` in [this commit](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-es_extensions/commit/bb0c188aa4c4714812db44bc78f79270dd637732). Next, I realized the `0.4.0-experimental2` with above changes and installed this version to repro ([commit](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Issue-WebpackDoesNotCuttOfTheUnusedFunctionality/commit/5fcfafc72e38874de2f4d4b8fe75823a67fd379c)).

Comment: Unfortunately, the bundle `index.js` has not been changed. If you have no time to check my repositories, may I ask you at least to share your working tests?

Comment: Sorry for the detour, but I have a much easier solution and have changed the answer to reflect that.  No need to change the es-extension `index.ts`.  It should remain as your original.  Instead add `"sideEffects":false` to the `package.json` of the top level project, and of course set `"module":"es2020"` (or similar es value) to both `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: I am very sorry to say that after all your help, but it's still zero effect. In [this commit](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-es_extensions/commit/4cd028a20eab03cc9fde2a65a613fba21c7f508b) I added missing `tsconfig.json` to distributable and realized `@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions
@0.4.0-experimental4`. In [this commit](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Issue-WebpackDoesNotCuttOfTheUnusedFunctionality/commit/78e9748cce0af9a2eebf9be89160109a149699ba) to repro repository, I added `"sideEffects":false` to `package.json`. I am really sorry about taking of your time,

Comment: but would you please to check the repositories? If you have the correctly working example, please, share it.

Comment: I put a pull request on your es_extensions repo.  Let me know!  Because it is definitely working here. `(()=>{"use strict";console.log(!1)})();` 39 bytes.

Comment: Do you mean the [newest repro repository](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Issue-WebpackDoesNotCuttOfTheUnusedFunctionality) woks in your environment?

Comment: Yes, downloaded yesterday evening (CA time -16 hrs rel to JP).  One difference is that I also set this in the `package.json` --- `  "dependencies": {
    "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions": "file:../yamato_daiwa-es_extensions/Distributable/"
  }` and then ran `npm i --save`.  That creates a symbolic link in the repro `node_modules` from `yamato_daiwa/es-extensions` to the local copy of `yamato_daiwa-es_extensions/Distributable/` in that parallel github copy I also downloaded.  You should not release that `file:...` syntax in your `package.json` but it is useful for development work.

Comment: Also I added code in both "scripts" to always clean (`rm -rf`) the build output before rebuilding.  Might not be necessary but I always worry.  I think you should delete some of your older messages, otherwise the stackexchange robot will eventually permit no new messages.

Comment: Thank you for the pull requests! I'll check and merge them during this week and report again.

Comment: I finally solved this problem! I apologize deeply because I missed the `sideEffects:false` in previous experiments. Accepted and upvoted your answer now!

Comment: Awesomely Good News!  Well done!