# How to provide Webpack tree-shaking for the usage of library distributing as ES20XX-modules

Tags: javascript, webpack

Unfortunately, there were not the working solution for the question [How to setup the TypeScript compiler for the library so that the unused modules will be cut off by Webpack in the dependents projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68340624/4818123) (for the Sep. 2021). The [solution suggested by Mr. Craig Hicks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68427637/4818123) works only locally and can not be used for the distributable library (I'll explan the details below).

However, from the Mr. Hicks's answer I knew that to make Webpack three-shaking available it's required to distribute the library as ES modules. It makes the issues for usage with Node.js native and [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node), but I afraid I will be downoved if try to consider all of these problems in single question.

### Target

The target library [@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-es_extensions) has a lot of functionality   and even in big applications a part of it will not be used. Theoretically, the Webpack's [three shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) could cut off the unused functionality, but actually it works with huge limitations as it will be shown in experiments below.

In the sample below, I am expecting that only `isUndefined` function will be bundled and any other functionality will NOT be:

```js
import { isUndefined } from "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions"

const test: string | undefined = "ALPHA";
console.log(isUndefined(test));

console.log("End of the script");
```

Here is the [full repository with reproduction](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Issue-WebpackDoesNotCuttOfTheUnusedFunctionality) consists from the local copy of `@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions@1.0.1-experimental2` (**Library** directory) and consuming project (**ConsumingProject** directory).

### Experiment 1: Close to real

In this experiment, I'll install the library as usual:

```json
{
  /* ... */
  "dependencies": {
    "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions": "1.0.1-experimental2"
  }
}
```

For the trial results, I'll remove all dependencies before install them:

```
npm run "Clear dependencies and reinstall"
```

where `Clear dependencies and reinstall` is:

```
"scripts": {
  "Clear dependencies and reinstall": "(rm node_modules || del node_modules /F /Q) && npm i",
  "Webpack:ProductionBuild": "webpack --mode production"
}
```

Next, I'll run the `"Webpack:ProductionBuild"`. In compiled `BrowserJS.js` we can see that whole library has been bundled (1 row and 21579 columns for minified version):

```js
(()=>{"use strict";function e(e){return null!==e}function t(e){return void 0!==e}function i(e,t){return void 0===e?t:e}
/* and so on ... */
```

This experiment available in the ["experiment1-close_to_real" branch](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Issue-WebpackDoesNotCuttOfTheUnusedFunctionality/tree/experiment1-close_to_real).

### Experiment 2: Get the library locally

Now the `ConsumptingProject` refers locally to `Library`:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions": "../Library"
}
```

It's important to clean previous `node_modules` and reinstall the dependencies:

```
npm run "Clear dependencies and reinstall"
```

Then,

```
npm run "Webpack:ProductionBuild"
```

The output `BrowserJS.js` has exactly `21579` columns as in previous experiment.

This experiment is available in [`experiment2-local_dependency` branch](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Issue-WebpackDoesNotCuttOfTheUnusedFunctionality/tree/experiment2-local_dependency).

### Experiment 3: Getting the library locally from `Distributable` directory

Now the library will be got from the `Distributable` directory of the `Library`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions": "../Library/Distributable"
}
```

This is what [Mr. Hicks suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68427637/4818123).

Let's clean the previous `node_modules` and reinstall the dependencies:

```
npm run "Clear dependencies and reinstall"
```

And if we execute the `"Webpack:ProductionBuild"`, the unused functinality finally will be cut off:

```js
(()=>{"use strict";console.log(!1),console.log("End of the script")})();
```

But what this solution matters for the published library?
Normally, the library will be installed as `@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions`, so what I and library users need three shaking works for this case. By other works, in the Experiment 1 we need same results as in this, third experiment.

This experiment available in ["experiment3-local_distributable" branch](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Issue-WebpackDoesNotCuttOfTheUnusedFunctionality/tree/experiment3-local_distributable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that declaring `"sideEffects": false` is the responsibility of *each package an application consumes*, so setting it in the application's root **package.json** isn't enough.

The **package.json** of `@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions` needs to include `"sideEffects": false`, so applications know *that package* is side-effect free. I tried this in your first example repo, and the final build gave me the expected:

```js
(()=>{"use strict";console.log(!1),console.log("End of the script")})();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The missing piece of puzzle was the `"sideEffects": false`... It solved the problem!