# How to distribute the NodeJS library written in TypeScript for both BrowserJS and NodeJS with available Webpack's three shaking?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

Like [lodash](https://lodash.com/), the library [@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-es_extensions#readme) suggests the common functions for both BrowserJS and NodeJS, but unlike lodash it has [single main file](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-es_extensions/blob/master/Source/index.ts) `index.js` with re-exports.

### Requirements

This library:

1. Must work in browser environment with Webpack (reached ✔️)
2. Must make available the Webpack's [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) (by other words, the cutting off of the unused functionality on production building) for BrowserJS where each kilobyte on count ([reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68340624/how-to-setup-the-typescript-compiler-for-the-library-so-that-the-unused-modules) ✔️).
3. Must work in NodeJS environment.
4. Must work with [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node)

### Main problem

The conflicting point is the **modules type**. To make the Webpack's tree shaking available, the [ES modules are required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68427637/4818123), but currently NodeJS supports CommonJS modules only, and in ts-node the ES modules support is limited (especially in the library exporting case).

What we have is:

| Modules type | BrowserJS (Webpack) | Tree shaking | NodeJS | ts-node |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **CommonJS** | Yes | No | Yes | Yes |
| **ES20XX** | Yes | Yes | No | Limited |

Because the tree shaking is critical for BroswerJS, it's already been decided to distribute the library by ES2020 modules. But this way, the support for NodeJS and ts-node will be lost.

Even if to build the NodeJS application with Webpack where it's not recommended to bundle the NodeJS libraries ([webpack node modules externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals) is being used to exclude them), application will crush if don't add the `@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions` with it's ES modules to excluding of **webpack node modules externals**.

### Repro

In [this repro](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Issue-WebpackDoesNotCuttOfTheUnusedFunctionality/tree/master/ConsumingProject), `npm run "Webpack:ProductionBuild"` will build the files `BrowserJS.js` and `NodeJS.js` for appropriate environment. Because the source code using `isUndefined` function of `"@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions"` library only, in `BrowserJS.js` must not be any other functionality (Webpack's tree shaking):

```js
(()=>{"use strict";console.log(!1),console.log("End of the script")})();
```

Well, it was the cleared challenge. The subject of this question is`NodeJS.js`:

```
(()=>{"use strict";const e=require("@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions");console.log((0,e.isUndefined)("ALPHA")),console.log("End of the script")})();
```

If we try to run it, we will have the error:

```
C:\Users\***\WebpackDoesNotCuttOfTheUnusedFunctionality\ConsumingProject\node_modules\@yamato-dai
wa\es-extensions\Distributable\index.js:6
export { default as formatNumberWith4KetaKanji } from "./Numbers/formatNumberWith4KetaKanji";
```

Now let's try to run it via ts-node (`npm run "TSNode test"`):

```
> ts-node index.ts

(node:18148) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\***\WebpackDoesNotCuttOfTheUnusedFunctionality\ConsumingProject\index.ts:1
import { isUndefined } from "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions";
```

Does in mean "you must change the library"?

### Note

This question has been asked before [TypeScript 4.5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-5-beta/) release. Maybe its new functionality will solve these problems?

Comment: `currently NodeJS supports CommonJS modules only` is wrong.

Comment: @morganney, Thank you for the comment. Well, I can't know everything in up-date state. May I ask you to add the details about this moment in your answer?

Comment: How about `umd` module type? It supports every javascript environments.

Comment: @h-sifat, will three shaking available with UMD?

Comment: I'm not sure but try setting `library: { type: "umd" }` in the `output` object of webpack configuration and use `es6` module syntax in your code. See if it works.

Comment: @h-sifat From the [Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/): "It relies on the static structure of ES2015 module syntax". Thus, dead-code elimination will not work with UMD.

Comment: But you're still using `es6 import & export` syntax in your source code. You're library bundle will use `umd` not your source code! If the output bundle doesn't use `umd` then  your library won't support every environment!

Comment: @h-sifat, Hmm, you gave me an idea. What if library could be distributed by CommonJS modules and `sideEffects: false` only matters? I'll check this hypothesis on weekend. Thanks for idea!

Comment: @h-sifat, my hypothesis was wrong... CommonJS modules has not been eliminated even with `sideEffects: false`. Well, I' sorry, but I has not time to experiment with UMD. I'll follow Eric Haynes's solution. Thank you for the comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"main"` entry in a `package.json` file should always be in commonjs format. The `"module"` entry should always be es modules. Right now, you have `"main"` pointing to es modules, which will not be resolved properly (your `ts-node` error, for example).

Generally, if you want to give consumers the option, you would create 2 builds in the distributable.

(you'll need to remove the comments in these json files)

```json
// tsconfig-esm.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES2020",

    // es module build target
    "outDir": "Distributable/esm"
  }
}
```

```json
// tsconfig-cjs.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",

    // commonjs build target
    "outDir": "Distributable/cjs",

    // the other one will build types, so not needed here
    "declaration": false
  }
}
```

Then, in your `package.json`:

```json
"main": "./Distributable/cjs/index.js",
"module": "./Distributable/esm/index.js",
"types": "./Distributable/esm/index.d.ts",
"scripts": {
  "build": "rimraf Distributable && tsc -p tsconfig-cjs.json && tsc -p tsconfig-esm.json",
  "Lint": "eslint Source Tests"
},
"files": [
  "Distributable"
],
"devDependencies": {
  "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
```

Note:

- you can call your scripts whatever you like, but `build` is idiomatic. The spaces would drive me nuts, as `npm run Rebuild distributable` wouldn't work. You have to either quote like `npm run 'Rebuild distributable'` or escape like `npm run Rebuild\ distributable`
- if you have a `"files"` entry in `package.json`, you no longer need `.npmignore`. This means "package only the files specified", which is much safer than having to remember to add every new file to an ignore list.
- I added the `rimraf` dependency, which is a common tool for deleting the dist directory in a platform-independent way. `del-cli` only works for windows.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you for detailed explanations with code and advices.