# What is best way to import _ from lodash?

Tags: javascript, webpack, lodash, bundle

I am using several functions from _ like sortBy .
But I do not need complete lodash.

I am using other funtions too from lodash like following

```
import map from 'lodash/map'
```

But when I try following

```
import _ from 'lodash/_'
```

I get error
cannot find module 'lodash/_'

If I simply use following it works

```
import _ from 'lodash'
```

But this will carry complete lodash in bundle file which increases size.
Can any one please suggest me optimum way to import _ from lodash ?

Comment: `_` *is* lodash (canonically). I don't understand the question--you're already importing just the functions you need (`import map from...`). I'm not sure what else you're trying to do.

Comment: "But this will carry complete lodash in bundle file which increases size. Can any one please suggest me optimum way to import _ from lodash ?" — This doesn't make any sense. Either you want `_` (which is all of lodash) **or** you want to import just the parts you want in order to reduce the bundle size. You can't have it both ways!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why webpack doesn't tree-shake the lodash when using "import \* as \_"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58741044/why-webpack-doesnt-tree-shake-the-lodash-when-using-import-as)

Comment: Thank you @DaveNewton I was not aware of `_` is lodash . Issue solved

Comment: (@Krishna Just out of curiosity, what did you think it was? On the [lodash homepage](https://lodash.com/) they differentiate between loading the full build and individual functions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install Lodash via NPM and then import only single functions. This works as follows:

```
import { merge, isEqual } from 'lodash';

// use them like regular functions
merge({ a: 1 }, { b: 2 });
```

Comment: This way of importing methods results in a higher bundle side. Instead, do this,  `import merge from 'lodash/merge';     import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual'; `

Comment: Could you elaborate why this would occur?
I figured since the code is compressed and tree shaked via a bundler like Rollup, that the bundle size would be the same.

Comment: Webpack can perform tree shaking automatically on ES6 modules. But it looks like lodash is built to use Common-JS modules. I think (lodash-es)[https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es] uses ES6 module. So if you're using lodash-es you can have the intended result with "tree-shaking"